# onUnbind isn't called when I call unbindService(serviceConnection);

Tags: java, android, android-service

I have a bound service and I have some problems with onUnbind method. When my app is destroyed clicking the back arrow or removing it from the recent apps, onUnbind  is called.

But consider this piece of code:

```
@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent)
{
    Log.e("onUnbind","onUnbind");
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

public void closeService()
{
    Log.e("closeService","closeService");
    unbindService(serviceConnection);
}
```

The method closeService is called when the app is definitely closed by a broadcast sent from onTaskRemoved in another service. So, when I close my app from recents, firstly onUnbind method is called and then closeService. However onUnbind isn't called again despite I unbind the service **again** in closeService. Furthermore the app should crash because of

> Android java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered.

Full error:

> E/ActivityThread: Activity com.playcollecchio.curio.toschgames.activities.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.playcollecchio.curio.toschgames.activities.MainActivity$1@2a07559 that was originally bound here
>                                                                                        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.playcollecchio.curio.toschgames.activities.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.playcollecchio.curio.toschgames.activities.MainActivity$1@2a07559 that was originally bound here
>                                                                                            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:1142)
>                                                                                            at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1036)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1966)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1949)
>                                                                                            at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:546)
>                                                                                            at com.playcollecchio.curio.toschgames.activities.MainActivity.onBind(MainActivity.java:159)
>                                                                                            at com.playcollecchio.curio.toschgames.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:86)
>                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
>                                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
>   01-03 21:49:02.675 25911-25911/com.playcollecchio.curio.toschgames E/METHOD: METHOD
>   01-03 21:49:02.675 25911-25911/com.playcollecchio.curio.toschgames E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to unbind to service com.playcollecchio.curio.toschgames.services.Client@892ff20 with Intent { cmp=com.playcollecchio.curio.toschgames/.services.Client }: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.playcollecchio.curio.toschgames.activities.MainActivity$1@2a07559
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleUnbindService(ActivityThread.java:3230)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:177)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1523)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
>                                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.playcollecchio.curio.toschgames.activities.MainActivity$1@2a07559
>                                                                                               at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1094)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:2000)
>                                                                                               at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:558)
>                                                                                               at com.playcollecchio.curio.toschgames.services.Client.onUnbind(Client.java:83)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleUnbindService(ActivityThread.java:3217)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:177) 
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1523) 
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910) 
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200) 
>   01-03 21:49:02.905 25911-25911/com.playcollecchio.curio.toschgames E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                        Process: com.playcollecchio.curio.toschgames, PID: 25911
>                                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to unbind to service com.playcollecchio.curio.toschgames.services.Client@892ff20 with Intent { cmp=com.playcollecchio.curio.toschgames/.services.Client }: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.playcollecchio.curio.toschgames.activities.MainActivity$1@2a07559
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleUnbindService(ActivityThread.java:3230)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:177)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1523)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
>                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.playcollecchio.curio.toschgames.activities.MainActivity$1@2a07559
>                                                                                            at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1094)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:2000)
>                                                                                            at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:558)
>                                                                                            at com.playcollecchio.curio.toschgames.services.Client.onUnbind(Client.java:83)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleUnbindService(ActivityThread.java:3217)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:177) 
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1523) 
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910) 
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)

In fact I'm trying to unbind a service which is already closed. However it seems that it isn't closed because this exception doesn't occur. But why is onUnbind called then?

Instead in this case (exclude closeService)

```
@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent)
{
    Log.e("onUnbind","onUnbind");
    unbindService(serviceConnection); 
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}
```

the app crashes because of that error and it's more reasonable. Why then isn't onUnbind called in the first case? And why doesn't the exception occur?

Comment: so when you call `Context#unbindService` twice do you expect `Service#onUnbind` to be called twice too?

Comment: @pskink yes, and I would like to see the exception

Comment: it does not work that way - `onUnbind` is called once and only when all the clients called `unbindService`

Comment: @pskink and why the exception?

Comment: @pskink posted the full log